# Java Project Dependency

Tags: java, dependencies, classpath

I recently made a project that uses the `javax.mail.jar` and when it run it outside of the dist folder (i.e. outside of the lib folder) it will give me the error java  `A Java Exception Has Occurred` .

This is  obviously because it needs its dependency (`javax.mail.jar`) but I have made other projects where the dependency is not needed and it used the same external jar.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to make it standalone?

Comment: Either launch using Maven, or create a `jar-with-dependencies`. (And in the future, always post the entire error message, even though in this case we're pretty sure it's a `ClassNotFoundException`.)

Comment: Try adding lib to your classpath

Comment: If your project Maven based then you can use Child-Parent project settings